# Drupal - get value from array

Tags: php, arrays, json, drupal, drupal-7

Maybe it's me but I can't get the values from the following array:

http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-2YV5V2Im.1427134235.png

What I want is to create a table where the headers are like this:

HomeTeam name | AwayTeam name | Match home_goals | Match away_goals

and then I have 9 rows with values.

My code so far:

```
$json = json_decode($server_output, true);
$days= $json['Calendar']['championship']['StageRound'][0]['matches'];

$header = ['HomeTeam name', 'AwayTeam name', 'Match home_goals', 'Match away_goals'];
$row = array();

foreach ($days as $key => $value) {
  ... here, I get always an error saying 'HomeTeam' is not an index...
}

$table = theme('table', array('header' => $header, 'rows' => $rows));

return $table;
```

Any help?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Added this code:

```
foreach ($days as $key => $value) {
  $hometeam = $days[0]['HomeTeam']['name'];
  $awayteam= $days[0]['AwayTeam']['name'];
  dpm($hometeam . ' - ' . $awayteam);
}
```

I have the index [0] in both lines inside the for cycle but I need it to be from 0 to 9 (the lenght of the array. That would solve my problem.

Comment: This snapshot is not matching your code. You are reading some "Calendar" element first. Where is it in you snapshot?!?

Comment: The 9 indexes I show in the picture are inside the 'matches' array ($days). It's not necessary fo show it, I think. If it's neccessary I can get a new screenshoot.

Comment: Here is the complete array with "Calendar" element: http://picpaste.com/pics/Untitled-YhfwLmiH.1427198366.png

Comment: Give us exact row that produces that error "Home team" is not an index.

Comment: I edited my first post. Can you kindly check it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foreach is already iterating trough that `matches` array, so you don't need that `[0]`. Go with:

```
  $hometeam = $value['HomeTeam']['name'];
  $awayteam= $value['AwayTeam']['name'];
```

or

```
  $hometeam = $days[$key]['HomeTeam']['name'];
  $awayteam= $days[$key]['AwayTeam']['name'];
```

if you like to access array over key...